# dots and whitespaces in filepath location, importing file in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, filepath

I have a file in windows remote server which I'm trying to read in a pandas dataframe. The file path has white spaces and dots in it. Following is what I'm trying to do but its not working for me.

file_location = '\\servername\foldername\folder name\5. folder_name\foldername - 0331v7\filename.txt'

df = pd.read_csv(filelocation, sep = '|')

I'm getting the no such file exists error. I tried to prefix the file_location string with r and thats not working too. I would appreciate if someone could help me with this.

Comment: could it be because of the different amount of slashes you are using? sometimes you use \\ and sometimes \ . Try being consistent or simply switching to  /

Comment: I'm using \\ to tell python that its a remote server and not a local drive on my machine like C:\

Comment: have you tried using str(filelocation) instead of 'filelocation' when you build your dataframe? It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Backslahes are used to tell the parser that the next character should be interpreted as an escapce sequence and not a regular character/operator.
For example if you want to print " you have to use the escape sequence \":

```
print("This is a quotation mark: \".")
```

Output:

```
This is a quotation mark: ".
```

If you are using a single backslash the next character is marked as escape sequence and therefore makes the path invalid. To get around this you can either use the escape sequence for backslash wich is \ or in most cases you can use a forward slash as most librarys automatically convert it to a backslash on windows.

Comment: This was helpful, adding the \ worked for me in the script. But in the end I did not go doing it this way. I created a command line argument and passed it to the script and in the command line argument I did not had to append any \ to escape anything, python took care of it for me